# Keep HashMap with object data while app is idle - Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a HashMap that contains data relevant to a specific Activity. The problem is that when the app is opened after being idle for some time, the HashMap is empty. I am fetching all the data in the main activity and storing the corresponding objects in a HashMap in a custom classc. Everything is working fine except some times when the app has been idle for a long time, then the HashMap returns null values for all keys.  What is the correct approach for keeping my data in the HashMap as long as there's an instance of my app running?

```
public class ApplicationCache {

    private static ApplicationCache cache;
    private static HashMap<String, Object> map;

    private ApplicationCache(){
        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    }

    public static ApplicationCache getInstance(){
        if(cache == null){
            cache = new ApplicationCache();
        }
        return cache;
    }

    public void setValue(String name, Object value){
        map.put(name, value);
    }

    public Object getValue(String name){
        return map.get(name);
    }

    public void removeValue(String name){
        map.remove(name);
    }

    public void clear(){
        map.clear();
    }

}
```

I am storing objects into the HashMap on a click event from a ListView in the main Activity:

```
ApplicationCache.getInstance().setValue("details", bankList.get(position));
```

In another activity i am reading values from this hashmap:

```
details = (DetailsVO) ApplicationCache.getInstance().getValue("details");
```

Comment: Is it possible by you to store hashmap object to SharedPreference ?\

Comment: Preferences accept only primitive types, so you can't put a complex Object in it

Comment: @Deepak make HashMap static

Comment: Ha.. I have done it already But it showing same null pointer exception

Comment: May be i done that If you want to check then i gave you a code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be the activity is again loading that is onCreate() is called. So save the state and restore it. Use onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState(). Let me know whether it worked or not.

Comment: how to store hasmap with objects data into onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState().. Please help me. I am beginner to android.

Comment: What are u storing in hashmap? If you are storing just strings then using JSON ur problem may get solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a simple piece of code to save map in preference and load the map from preference. No GSON functions required. I just used a map having String as key and Boolean as a value.

```
private void saveMap(Map<String,Boolean> inputMap){
            SharedPreferences pSharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyVariables", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            if (pSharedPref != null){
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(inputMap);
                String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();
                Editor editor = pSharedPref.edit();
                editor.remove("My_map").commit();
                editor.putString("My_map", jsonString);
                editor.commit();
            }
        }

private Map<String,Boolean> loadMap(){
            Map<String,Boolean> outputMap = new HashMap<String,Boolean>();
            SharedPreferences pSharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyVariables", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            try{
                if (pSharedPref != null){       
                    String jsonString = pSharedPref.getString("My_map", (new JSONObject()).toString());
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                    Iterator<String> keysItr = jsonObject.keys();
                     while(keysItr.hasNext()) {
                            String key = keysItr.next();
                            Boolean value = (Boolean) jsonObject.get(key);
                            outputMap.put(key, value);
                        }
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return outputMap;
        }
```

Comment: i worked on that and it's working for me please chech weather it's work for you or not.

Comment: First tell me is it working for you or not in your case ?

Answer (score 0):

I have written this simple methods to store Objects in internal file storage, you can use it, just replace JSONObject with ur Hashmap

```
public static void writeToCache(String fileName, JSONObject jObject) {
            ObjectOutput out;
            try {
                if(!(new File(BASE_PATH)).exists()){
                    new File(BASE_PATH).mkdirs();
                }
                out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
                        new File(BASE_PATH+fileName)));
                out.writeObject(jObject.toString());
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


public static JSONObject getJsonObject(String fileName) {
        ObjectInputStream in;
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(BASE_PATH+fileName)));
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(in.readObject().toString());
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException | JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //e.printStackTrace();
            return jsonObject;
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for response.. how to store hasmap with objects data into onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState().. Please help me. I am beginner to android.

Comment: onSaveInstanceState put your hashmap in Bundle object with putSerializable(key,Hashmap) method, and you get that Bundle in onCreate() method

Comment: dont forget to check key is exist in bundle before getting hashmap from Bundle in onCreate method